# Can't edit Datagridview in C# when using UNION

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a Windows Form Application with Datagridview. Enable editing is TRUE, but I can't edit the fields inside the datagrid. I'm using datasource which has SQL UNION. When using the query without the UNION, it's fine.

I'm talking about not be able to even start changing the fields in the grid with F2 or double click. I have to use union here, but it seems to be a problem and I can't find solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more code would help, but it seems as though your SQL Datasource is smart enough to know that the query is readonly.

As you said, when you take off the union, it works fine.  So setting the grid to a datasource of

`SELECT FOO FROM MyTable`

Could cause a corresponding update query of `UPDATE MyTable` to be created.  No such corresponding query exists with a

`SELECT FOO FROM MyTable UNION SELECT FOO FROM MyOtherTable`

So the grid is probably smart enough to prevent you from editing those fields.  This is the same behavior when you bind a DGV to a collection of C# Objects; those columns that are read only are never able to be edited (how could they);

Comment: If I want to edit the row with update statement, I have a flag in the both select queries that tells me from which table is the row, so I can know which table to edit. But that is not the problem... If someone knows a solution, it would be appreciated :)

Comment: @Andrej: I think this *is* the problem. Your flag is great for you but doesn't mean anything to the system, so your UNION query data source is read-only and thus the DataGridView doesn't allow it to be edited. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yztkd864.aspx